# Cygwin uses Windows commands

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin

I'd like to build a a library with Cygwin.

I've installed Cygwin on Windows 8.1 and added it to the windows's path.

I still get this error:

[image]

Cygwin still want to start Windows' FIND command instead of the Unic version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$PATH`. It should have Cygwin's `/bin`, etc., directories in the front. If it does not, fix it. If that does not help, check that you have actually installed the required package for the `find` command. It should be in the `findutils` package.

Comment: It's in the first place.

Comment: @erbal: Updated.

Comment: It's installed:
$ cygcheck.exe find
Found: C:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe

Comment: @erbal: Your `$PATH` must be messed up. Please try to set it with `export PATH=/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32`.

Comment: In this case I get the error: make command not found, unofortunately.

Comment: @erbal: Are you sure you have Cygwin's make package installed?

Comment: Yes, as you see in the picture above, normally it starts. But it cannot use the Unix kind of find command.